# FCM Cloud Messaging not show in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have a problem for showing FCM notification in my android aplication, i have follow docs of firebase cloud messaging[docs fcms android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) but still not working

Comment: What is the problem and how did you try?

Comment: message  body show in terminal run but not show in android app

Comment: If you follow all the steps then there is no reason not to work

Comment: Probably you missed something, Add your code work for further investigate

Comment: D/MyFirebaseMsgService: From: 144320645359
D/MyFirebaseMsgService: Message Notification Body: this is message 1
D/Notification: allPendingIntents

Comment: but not reaction on my android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your targetSdkVersion is more than Oreo, you should make a channel for notification like the following code.

Try checking it if you missed it or not.

```
private void setChannel(NotificationManager nm) {
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
            >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if(mChannel == null)
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_FOR_OTG, CHANNEL_NAME_FOR_OTG, importance);
        nm.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
}
```